# Java 2d cube effect using shear

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, 2d, affinetransform

I have been stuck on this for about a week, I have searched all over the internet trying to find a solution of how to create a 2d cube effect using shear, I have tried numorous equations and this is the closest I have gotten in a week, it's purely math I believe but I can't figure it out.  It is for a Multiplayer game, here is a video on Youtube of what I currently have with shearing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0qP7T0k6xk

Here is my code:

```
public void addWall(Graphics2D g2d, ImageIcon img, int objX, int objY, int dir) {
    //objX = objX/16;
    objX = objX*32;
    //objY = objY/16;
    objY = (objY+4)*32;
    int OffsetX = screen.width;
    int OffsetY = screen.height*0;

    if(dir == 1) {
        //g2d.drawImage(img.getImage(), (((2*objX)+OffsetX)-(player.x*2)), (((2*objY)+OffsetY)-(player.y*2)) ,32*SCALE, ((32*SCALE)*-2)-(player.y-objY), null);
    } else if(dir == 0) {
        g2d.drawImage(img.getImage(), (((2*objX)+OffsetX)-(player.x*2)), (((2*objY)+OffsetY-(32*SCALE))-(player.y*2)) ,32*SCALE, ((32*SCALE)*-2)-(player.y-objY), null);

    }

    double skewX = (((player.x-objX)*2)*.100)*.1;
    double skewY = 0;
    //int x = (skewX < 0) ? -skewX*(32) : 0;


    AffineTransform reset = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance((-skewX*100) , 0);

    at.shear(skewX, skewY);

    //g2d.translate((((2*objX)+OffsetX)-(player.x*2)), (((2*objY)+OffsetY)-(player.y*2)));

    // g2d.scale(SCALE, (((SCALE)*-2)-(player.y-objY)));
    g2d.setTransform(at);

    g2d.drawImage(img.getImage(), (((2*objX)+OffsetX)-(player.x*2)), (((2*objY)+OffsetY)-(player.y*2)) ,32*SCALE, ((32*SCALE)*-2)-(player.y-objY), null);

    g2d.setTransform(reset);
    //g2d.dispose();

}

public void addRoof(Graphics2D g2d, ImageIcon img, int objX, int objY) {
    //objX = objX/16;
    objX = objX*32;
    //objY = objY/16;
    objY = (objY+2)*32;
    int shadowY = (objY+3)*32;
    int OffsetX = screen.width;
    int OffsetY = screen.height*0;

    /* SHADOW */
    /* SHADOW */
    ImageIcon shadow = new ImageIcon("./res/shadowPixel.png");
    g2d.drawImage(shadow.getImage(), (2*objX+OffsetX)-(player.x*2), (2*objY+(32*SCALE)+OffsetY)-(player.y*2), 32*SCALE, 32*SCALE, null);
    /* SHADOW */
    /* SHADOW */

    g2d.drawImage(img.getImage(), (3*objX+OffsetX)-(player.x*3), (3*objY+OffsetY)-(player.y*3), 32*SCALE, 32*SCALE, null);
}
```